# Javascript Look behind

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to mimic a look behind in Javascript,

I want to match the string "object.all" but not "object.call". I've tried:

```
new RegExp('(?!(\\.))all')
```

But both examples are matched, what I want is a look behind to test if there's a `.` (dot) just behind `all`, can someone explain me what's wrong in my regex?

Thanks in advance

---

This one is good:

```
'object.all'.replace(new RegExp('(?!(\\.))all'), 'foo') 
// => object.foo
```

For this one i expect the result to be "object.call" :

```
'object.call'.replace(new RegExp('(?!(\\.))all'), 'foo')
// => object.cfoo
```

Comment: Have you checked [this site](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp because i use it like this:`"object.call".replace(new RegExp('(?!(\\.))all'), 'foo')`.

Comment: @m.buettner Your link seems damn complex :)

Comment: @jules I've updated my answer - sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: Look-behinds were added in the 2018 specification. They work in chrome, but not [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this seems complex this will get the job done:

```
function replaceAll(string, replacement) {
  var output = string.replace(/(\.)?all/g, function($0, $1) {
    return $1 ? $1 + replacement : $0;
  });
  return output;
}

var test1 = replaceAll("object.all", "foo");
var test2 = replaceAll("object.call", "foo");

console.log(test1); // object.foo
console.log(test2); // object.call
```

I have used the article ([Mimicking Lookbehind in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)) that @m.buettner linked in the comments before in a bit of code I was working on earlier this year.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your new example provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that its still a lookahead. Because of that, its checking to see if the dot exists in the same spot as the "a", instead of in the spot just behind.